# Problem when an array element i'm trying to filter for does not exist

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

I have some code that gets a key from firebase, and compares it with a key stored locally in a text file.  If there is a match, it checks an additional read/unread parameter, and then marks a variable as "Read" or "Unread".

The code works fine as long as every key I pull from Firebase exists in the text file.  However, I get an "Index out of bounds" crash if a key from Firebase does not exist in my local file.

The code in question is as per below:

```
func readFile(){

    let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("output.txt")
    do {

        let textStringFromFile = try String(contentsOf: filename, encoding: .utf8)

        var result: [(messageID: String, readStatus: String)] = []

        let rows = textStringFromFile.components(separatedBy: "\n")
        for row in rows {
            let columns = row.components(separatedBy: ",")
            result.append((columns[0], columns[1]))
        }


        let filteredMessageID = result.filter { $0.messageID == (nominationKeyForReadStatus) }

        var messageIDElement = filteredMessageID.map { $0.messageID }
        var readStatusElement = filteredMessageID.map { $0.readStatus }

        if readStatusElement[0] == "1" && nominationKeyForReadStatus == messageIDElement[0] {

            readStatusFromFunction = "Read"
        }
        else {
            readStatusFromFunction = "Unread"
        }
    }
    catch{

        }

    }
```

The crash seems to happen when filteredMessageID has 0 values.  How do I account for this case?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have several lines of code that make assumptions about the number of objects in some arrays. Eliminate those assumptions. Write code that properly checks for the correct number of objects before accessing specific indexes. Never assume remote has a specific format. Things can change or you may get unexpected results. Code defensively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a pre check before accessing the index for `messageIDElement`, `readStatusElement` and `filteredMessageID` that it not having count 0.

```
if filteredMessageID.count != 0 {
   if readStatusElement.count != 0 && messageIDElement != 0 {
    // Your code
  }
}
```